# docker stack deploy got error code 3 and "driver name: if driver is specified name is required"

Tags: docker

I was following the `Docker` tutorial and on Part 3: Services ([link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#scale-the-app))

When I ran this command, I got the shown error:

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab
Creating network getstartedlab_webnet
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 
desc = driver name: if driver is specified name is required
```

**Version:**

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# docker-latest --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 6774275/1.13.1
```

**Updated 1: My `docker-compose.yml`**

I was using the same `docker-compose.yml` as suggested in the
tutorial:

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: localhost:5000/leeyuiwah/get-started:part2
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

**Update 2: Another variant of the file**

Based on some discussion on this [thread](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29809), I also tweaked the file
to use a slightly different definition of network.  But this
file got the same error as the above.

```
[root@pecan-9A firstDocker]# cat docker-compose.v2.yml
version: "3.0"
services:
  web:
    image: localhost:5000/leeyuiwah/get-started:part2
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks: [hello]

networks:
  hello:
    driver: overlay
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.17.0.0/16
```

Comment: You need to provide the `yml` file. The problem is there. One clue would be to get rid of that driver part from `yml`, and let docker use default one.

Comment: Post your compose file as this is a error in your compose file itself

Comment: Thanks!  I posted two variants of my `docker-compose.yml` as updates to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while following the same guide you are using. The problem seems to be from using the 'docker' package from the OS and not the package from the docker repository. During the setup guide they ask you to add their repository, remove docker and docker.io packages, and then install 'docker-ce'.

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

Once I did this, I no longer ran into the error.